# Disable specific JavaScript when Bootstrap modal is shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have JavaScript running that somehow disables vertical panning on shown modals on mobile devices. Thus a user is not able to see all the content of a modal.

Is there a way to disable this JavaScript every time a modal is shown?

Following code in the JavaScript seems to be responsible for disabling panning:

```
  var my_menu = new Menu({
    menuID:"my_menu",
    menuItemClass:"menu",
  });
```

When I remove it panning works perfectly!

So my idea was to run another function every time a modal is shown that removes the code above.

Does that make sense & how could this be achieved?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Most of Bootstrap's JavaScript components have [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#events) you can leverage. You'd disable the script on `show.bs.modal` and enable it on `hide.bs.modal`.

I suggest that any time you use a library's features you review the entire documentation so you're aware of what it offers.

Comment: Thanks! How would you enable / disable the script?

Comment: That's a separate question and I have no idea what `Menu()` is. It may be a simple as overwriting `my_menu` to nullify it, but the library may have a destroy function you need to use.